# Q: Vaadin 14: server port not picked up from application.yaml if no application.properties is present

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin14

I'm trying to configure a different port to be uses by my vaadin backend. For some reason, defining a different server port that is defined in an applaction.yaml ONLY gets picked up if an application.properties file is also present. This .properties file may be completly empty, but if it isnt there, the application uses the default 8080 port for the tomcat.
The strange thing is: Other things that I set in the application.yaml DO get picked up correctly regardless of the existence of an application.properties file. (like e.g. "banner-mode").

As a workaround, I keep the (empty) application.properties in my src/main/resources folder. Nevertheless, this feels kind of strange.

Comment: There does appear to be some role for the application.properties file - if you look at https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/integrations/spring/tutorial-spring-configuration this is mentioned along with the fact that you can still use any name/source.